# Is there are any guide/documentation about byobu (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, byobu

For example, I can't understand, how to disable F-keys by default.
And I can't understand why 0-window doesn't get new name if I started some program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not 14.04 specific, there is a quick-start guide available at http://j.mp/byobu-help, which does answer your "toggle all of Byobu's keybindings off" question, at least (*hint*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Your question here actually inspired me to write [this blog post](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/08/learn-byobu-in-10-minutes-while.html) and create [this 10-minute instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NawuGmcvKus&feature=youtu.be).  Enjoy!

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*